# Volume of tetrahedron defined by four vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Given four vectors $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, which are vertices of a tetrahedron, can we find volume by considering it as $1/4$ of the volume of the parallelepiped whose volume is $[(a-b) \times (b-d)]\cdot (c-b)$?

As a more complicated solution, I'd find the base area $A = \frac{1}{2}\Vert (a-b)\times (b-d)\Vert$, and the height $h = \Vert (c-b) - proj_{span\{a-b, b-d\}}(a-b,b-d)\Vert$.

Please let me know if you find either the first or the second methods to be correct.

Comment: For what it's worth, the volume of the tetrahedron is one-_sixth_ the volume of the parallelipiped, not one-fourth.

Answer (score 1):

Your first method is correct, taking the absolute value and then  $1/6$ of it, as already commented ($1/2$ for the base area, $1/3$ of base-area x h).
Your second method is unclear to me.

Comment: Why is my 2nd method not correct? In that case we take the area of the triangular base of the tetrahedron and then the perpendicular projection of the "top" vertice on the plane spanned by the "bottom" sides of the base; and apply the same formula for the area of a tetrahedron.

Comment: I did not say it is not correct, just that I did not understand the formulation. As you explained it is correct, and practically equivalent to the first, but then you should have written something like $h = \Vert (c-b)\Vert - \Vert Proj (c-b) onto span_{\{a-b, b-d\}}\Vert$, which however is not a standard writing.